# Optimizar mi código MySQL con JSON

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, api

Tengo un dilema respecto al rendimiento de mi sistema, se trata de un CRUD donde muestro en una tabla HTML los registros obtenidos con MySQL,
supongamos:

```
select nombre, apellido from personas
```

Y con un `while` recorro los resultados y los muestro dentro de un `<tr></tr>`.

Ahora bien, recién estoy probando la tecnología JSON como API; es decir, mediante JavaScript consulto invoco mi `api.php` y esta me devuelve en formato JSON los mismos resultados de esta consulta:

```
select nombre, apellido from personas
```

El resultado lo recorro y genero los `<tr>`, pero mediante JavaScript.
La pregunta es: ¿Qué es más eficiente? ¿Mostrar directamente los datos en mi tabla o hacer un llamado al API que me genera un JSON?

Nota: obviamente en menos de 100 registros mostrarlos directamente seria la mejor opción pero, por ejemplo, cuando se trata de generar *options* para un select o por ejemplo si son mas de 10,000 registros.

Comment: Hablar de eficiencia es _complicado_, en el sentido que hay que definir cosas como: ¿eficiente para quién? ¿eficiencia en términos de qué?. Dicho esto, generalmente no se desarrollan API's para hacer los sistemas más eficientes (en general), sino más flexibles y más fáciles de extender, por ejemplo, hacer más fácil la reutilización de la lógica de negocios con nuevos _front ends_ (hoy es una aplicación web, mañana se le suman 3 aplicaciones móviles), y de integración con otros sistemas.

Comment: @jachguate en todo caso seria cual de las 2 formas consumas mas recursos y es mas rapida de mostrar los registros ?

Comment: Por eso pregunto, eficiente para quién. No es lo mismo eficiencia en el servidor, que en la red, que en el cliente. Rápido de mostrar, que es un aspecto a medir en el cliente, diría que generalmente va a ser más rápido generar el HTML en el servidor, hacerlo viajar al cliente y mostrarlo _de un plumazo_. La excepción a esto, es cuando la verbosidad del HTML sea significativamente mayor a la del JSON, en cuyo caso, puede llegar a ser más rápido hacer viajar los datos en este formato. Aunque esto también puede hacerse sin usar una API.

Comment: Pero no hay respuestas absolutas en este tema sin hacer un benchmark en la implementación real, para medir los tiempos de un número significativo de ejecuciones, en condiciones más o menos reales de los principales cuellos de botella (por ejemplo, de ancho de banda, carga del servidor) y comparar dichos resultados.

Comment: Para hablar de "más recursos", nuevamente habría que definir si hablamos de más recursos en el cliente, o más recursos en el servidor? Estos suelen tener una relación de proporción inversa, aunque no siempre es así. Utilizar un API tiende a consumir más recursos (CPU, memoria) en el cliente, y menos en el servidor. No utilizarla, tiende a utilizar mas en el servidor y menos en el cliente. La relación, sin embargo, no es lineal.

Comment: a rasgos generales, para mostrar 1,000 resultados en una tabla que metodo usaras ? una consulta directa de lado del servidor o una consulta al api que me genere un json del lado del cliente ?